# How to get the URL of the currently executing PHP script?

Tags: php

How do I get the URL of the currently executing PHP script?

For example, the URL `http://www.domain.com/folder/script.php` sends a request to `/var/www/domain/folder/script.php`.

In `script.php`, I want to echo `http://www.domain.com/folder/` (not `/var/www/domain/folder/`, not `http://www.domain.com/folder/script.php`). What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that sophisticated, but here it goes:

```
<?php
    $scriptFolder = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    $scriptFolder .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    echo $scriptFolder;
?>
```

Comment: A better solution might use $_SERVER[’SCRIPT_NAME’] instead of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. And what about "https://"?

Comment: @powerboy: did you read the PHP documentation pertaining to $_SERVER? I believe php.net and its comments cover everything you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Google search would have answered your question. Here's the result.

http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/_SERVER_PHP.htm

Comment: $_SERVER[’PHP_SELF’], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and $_SERVER[’SCRIPT_NAME’] return path with script file name instead of the path alone. I want to know if there is a variable set to the path alone.

Comment: See solution by Mihai Iorga below. PHP doesn't come with that function out of the box, but with about half a minute of time, you can get the desired functionality. That takes less time than posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer for this question, it seems there isn't an easy one.

Then it hit me: it is because it is not always possible to get the current script url.

PHP can include a file anywhere in the file system, as long as the user running the process has access to it, it will work. But then, that means it is possible to include scripts outside the webserver's root directory - hence impossible to have a url. I believe that is the reason there is not straight forward function to do that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13920864)

Comment: Well, it is a question without an answer, and I explain why I think it is the case.