# How do I use PHP to grab the name of the file?

Tags: php, linux

what I want to do is PHP to look at the url and just grab the name of the file, without me needing to enter a path or anything (which would be dynamic anyway). E.G.

http://google.com/info/hello.php, I want to get the 'hello' bit.

Help?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902254/php-how-to-get-the-url-of-the-currently-executing-script/2902267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `basename` and `explode` to get name without extension:

```
$name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$name_array = explode('.', $name);
echo $name_array[0];
```

Comment: Actually this is not always correct, what if you have an .htaccess which rewrites the url?

Comment: `basename` is not suitable for URIs. Consider `basename('/foo/bar?baz/quux')` returning `quux` instead of `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = __FILE__;
```

Now you can split this on the dot, for example

```
$filenameChunks = split(".", $filename);

$nameOfFileWithoutDotPHP = $filenameChunks[0];
```

Comment: basename function is way better, this will fail for foo.file.php etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is safe way to easily grab the filename without extension

```
$info = pathinfo(__FILE__);
$filename = $info['filename'];
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains the requested URI path and query. You can then use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to get the path and [`basename`](http://php.net/basename) to get just the file name:

```
basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

```
$file = basename(__FILE__); // hello.php
$file = explode('.',$file); // array
unset($file[count($file)-1]); // unset array key that has file extension
$file = implode('.',$file); // implode the pieces back together
echo $file; // hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to this with `parse_url` combined with `pathinfo`

Here's an example

```
$parseResult = parse_url('http://google.com/info/hello.php');
$result = pathinfo($parseResult['path'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

`$result` will contain "hello"

More info on the functions can be found here:
[parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
[pathinfo](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)